# Authorising POST to Vimeo API with C# HttpClient

Tags: c#, .net, vimeo-api

I am trying to make a POST to the Vimeo API but I am getting `401 Authorization Required`.

This is my code for the request (I am just sending the first request that the docs says should return me a ticket ID for uploading).

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.vimeo.com");
var byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(accessToken);
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
            new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(byteArray));

var form = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>()
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("type","POST")
            });
var response = await client.PostAsync("/me/videos", form);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

I also tried adding access token like this:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
            new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", accessToken);
```

It always return 401.

What is proper way to add the access token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how header must be:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
            new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
```